# Ember Observe DOM Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, ember.js

I am attempting to build a form element in ember. The form element contains a Ember view/component to upload a picture, once the picture is uploaded a thumbnail of the picture is displayed. The form also contains a reset and submit button. When clicking "reset" the file input box clears so I know the "onreset" DOM event is triggering. Let me attempt to diagram:

```
Accordion: {
    photoUpload: {
          fileUpload: {
              input: {}
          },
          resetButton,
          saveButton
    }
}

Accordion: simply houses components and handles its own open/close actions.  
photoUpload: has both a template and a view/controller.  
    photoUpload.hbs: has a form element that houses the fileUpload component and the two buttons.  
    photoUpload.js: handles the actions from the template, such as making the call to the web services.
fileUpload: Handles the uploading of files, determining there type and displaying a preview/thumbnail if the file is an image.
input: handles file browsing
```

So the real problem I'm trying to solve is how to kick off an action/funciton/event from the resetButton that can be heard/executed in the sister element fileUpload. When I hit execute my reset button I clear out the input element I am thinking I need to some how observe a property in this input component from my fileUpload component to then clear out the image preview.

Here is an example of the photoUpload template:

```
<p>Upload a photo.</p>
<form {{action 'savePhoto' on='submit'}}>
    {{view FileUpload showPreview=true showProgress=true valueBinding="photo" fileBinding="view.file"}}
    <div class="controls">
        {{#view Button type="secondary" function="reset" action="resetPhoto"}}Cancel{{/view}}
        <input class="primary" type="submit" value="Save">
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is an example of the input component:

```
function() {
    var _InputElement = Ember.View.extend({
        tagName:           'input',
        attributeBindings: ['type', 'name', 'value', 'readonly', 'disabled', 'required'],

        typeBinding:     'parentView.type',
        idBinding:       'parentView.GUID',
        valueBinding:    'parentView.value',
        readonlyBinding: 'parentView.readonly',
        disabledBinding: 'parentView.disabled',
        requiredBinding: 'parentView.required',
        nameBinding:     'parentView.name',

        change: Ember.aliasMethod( '_updateValue' ),
        keyUp:  Ember.aliasMethod( '_updateValue' ),

        _updateValue: function() {
            var old     = this.get( 'value' );
            var current = this.$().val();

            if( current != old ) { // -- value actually changed
                this.set( 'value', this.$().val());
            }
        }
    });

    return Ember.View.extend({
        classNames:        ['input'],
        classNameBindings: ['error:error', '_typeClass'],
        attributeBindings: ['data-label', 'data-name', 'readonly', 'disabled', 'required'],
        _InputElement:     _InputElement,

        type:                 'text', // text, password, radio, checkbox, select, etc
        error:                null,
        label:                null,
        prefix:               null,
        postfix:              null,
        name:                 null,
        value:                null,
        readonly:             false,
        disabled:             false,
        showInputBeforeLabel: false,

        'data-name': function() {
            var name = this.get( 'name' );
            return (!Ember.isEmpty( name ) ? name.camelize() : undefined);
        }.property( 'name' ),

        'data-label': function() {
            var label = this.get( 'label' );
            return (!Ember.isEmpty( label ) ? label.camelize() : undefined);
        }.property( 'label' ),

        _typeClass: function() {
            return 'input-%@'.fmt( this.get( 'type' ));
        }.property( 'type' ),

        _InputElementGUID: function() {
            var childViews = this.get('childViews');

            if ( childViews && childViews[0] ) { // -- only works if there is ONE child view, as in, ONE _InputElement
                return childViews[0].get('elementId');
            }
        }.property( '_InputElement', 'childViews.[]' ),

        _yieldTemplate: '{{yield}}',

        _labelTemplate:     '<label {{bind-attr for="view._InputElementGUID"}}>{{view.label}}</label>',
        _preLabelTemplate:  function() { return '{{#if view.label}}{{#unless view.showInputBeforeLabel}}' + this.get( '_labelTemplate' ) + '{{/unless}}{{/if}}'; }.property(),
        _postLabelTemplate: function() { return '{{#if view.label}}{{#if     view.showInputBeforeLabel}}' + this.get( '_labelTemplate' ) + '{{/if}}{{/if}}'; }.property(),

        _errorTemplate: '{{#if view.error}}<label class="error form-error" {{bind-attr for="view._InputElementGUID"}}>{{view.error}}</label>{{/if}}',

        _prefixTemplate:  '{{#if view.prefix }}<div class="prefix  input-prefix" >{{view.prefix }}</div>{{/if}}',
        _postfixTemplate: '{{#if view.postfix}}<div class="postfix input-postfix">{{view.postfix}}</div>{{/if}}',

        layout: function() {
            return Ember.Handlebars.compile( ''
                + this.get('_preLabelTemplate') + '\n'
                + this.get('_prefixTemplate') + '\n'
                + this.get('_yieldTemplate') + '\n'
                + this.get('_postfixTemplate') + '\n'
                + this.get('_postLabelTemplate') + '\n'
                + this.get('_errorTemplate')
            )
        }.property(),

        template: Ember.Handlebars.compile( '{{view view._InputElement}}' )
    });
});
```

and the input component is used like so:

```
'<div class="input-file-button-wrapper">{{view view._InputElement}}</div>\
    <div class="input-file-preview-wrapper">\
        <img {{bindAttr src="view.file"}} {{bindAttr title="view.fileName"}}/>\
    </div>'
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/observers/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up needing to use a simple binding. I had misunderstood how bindings worked in Ember and was thinking that bound variables/properties could only be used within the action associated to that view/component instantiation. When in reality you can use any of your bound variables inside of the component that is instantiating the other components. My solution was to bind my variable "haveUploadedFile" that is found in the fileUpload component. Then in the action that gets kicked off with my reset button I set that variable to false.

Hope this helps someone down the road.

fileUpload.hbs now looks like this:

```
<p>Upload a headshot.</p>
<form {{action 'savePhoto' on='submit'}}>
    {{view Vember.FileUpload showPreview=true showProgress=true valueBinding="photo" fileBinding="view.file" haveUploadedFileBinding="view.haveUploadedFile"}}
    <div class="controls">
        {{#view Vember.Button type="secondary" function="reset" action="resetPhoto"}}Cancel{{/view}}
        <input class="primary" type="submit" value="Save">
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just have this in your view: `<button {{action reset}}>Reset</button>` and let that action handle what you want to do.

Comment: it's better if you provide more information. An example would be helpful.

Comment: I have an accordion component with a "photoUpload" component inside of if. Inside of the "photoUpload" there is a "fileUpload" component and two buttons. So I am using a action to catch the button presses to then make ajax calls to services, but I don't see how I can modify something in the "fileUpload" component when I'm at the "photoUpload" level. I'll update my post.